# Device to Communicate with an Epson Projector via USB

Tags: android, usb, epson, projector

I am trying to control an Epson projector via USB with an Android device.
I need to be able to turn it on and off.
 I managed to connect to it with the Android's [UsbHost api](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

My questions are:

1. Using the UsbHost api, I'm not sure which `interface` and `endpoint` should I use
2. I found [this manual](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/pl600p/pl600pcm.pdf) which lists some commands for controlling an Epson projector using the ESC/VP21 protocol. Is there a way to use it on Android/Java?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try reading about adb commands, I used them in my system and they work like a charm. You'd have to study about them though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! but ADB is for controlling an Android device from a PC, thats not what I'm trying to do. I am trying to control an Epson projector from an Android device

Comment: You don't need to repeat the `android` **tag** in the post **title**.